# Selenium does not click on button although ID is given (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

**I have just started with Selenium and I wanted to use it to test a locahost website.
When trying to click on a button it does not work anymore.
I've tried it with xpath which did not work either.**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login");
            driver.findElement(By.id("vaadinLoginUsername")).sendKeys("t.user1@test.de");
            driver.findElement(By.id("vaadinLoginPassword")).sendKeys("Password");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();



Exception: 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-BA77QHA', ip: '172.25.208.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.141, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c..., userDataDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58190}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: fba6ad40096f8e45f066b042236f1412
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at com.ideentool.application.Application.main(Application.java:66)
```

[The HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce8Iv.png)

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your elemet is not Interactable. Use smart wait.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement signInButton;
signInButton= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("button")));
signInButton.click();
```

Comment: Liked the term _`smart wait`_ :)

Comment: Now i am having another exception:                                                              Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: button (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval).